# Parse Json data for Core-Plot

Tags: json, parsing, core-plot

How do I go about parsing this https://coinbase.com/api/v1/prices/historical? into x (time) and y (price) arrays to create a line chart using core-plot (or other recommendations)? I'm up to here:

```
-(void)URL
{   
    dispatch_async(coinbaseQueue, ^{

        NSString* coinbaseURL= @"https://coinbase.com/api/v1/prices/historical?";
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:coinbaseURL]];
        if (data == nil)
        {
             NSLog(@"url: loading ERROR");
           [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self selector:@selector(URL) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];//was NO

        }else
        {
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
        }
    });
}
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    //parse out the json data
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1
                                                         options:kNilOptions
                                                           error:&error];
//parse
}
```

also any further help, links to tutorials for core-plot. much appreciated 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very simple dataformat. From the result the link you posted returns I don't see any JSON involved. Retrieve the result as a simple string and use NSString's [- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString%3a) to first separate lines (use the line break as separator string). Then for each line do the same but this time with comma as separator. This will give you an array with 2 entries for each line (a date and a price). Now convert both values to NSDate and NSNumber and store them in your x and y data arrays, respectively.

For How-Tos, tutorials etc. [read coreplot's wiki](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/wiki).

Comment: I am having trouble with: "Then for each line do the same but this time with comma as separator" on the second" now that the data is an array NSString's coponentsSeparatedByString does not work. My array looks like: "2014-03-14T20:46:58-07:00,634.95",
    "2014-03-14T20:37:24-07:00,632.12",
    "2014-03-14T20:26:59-07:00,634.01", ... Also once separated by the comma and turned into NSDate/NSNumber how do I separate the every other line into their x and y arrays? Thanks!